# Creating a zod enum from an object

Tags: typescript, validation, object, types, zod

I have this **object**:

```
const properties = [
  { value: "entire_place", label: "The entire place" },
  { value: "private_room", label: "A private room" },
  { value: "shared_room", label: "A shared room" },
] as const;
```

I need to use it with zod in order to

1. **Validate** and parse my data on the backend
2. Create a **typescript union type** with those possible values `"entire_place" | "shared_room" | "private_room"`

According to the **zod documentation**, i can do this:

```
const properties = [
  { value: "entire_place", label: "The entire place" },
  { value: "private_room", label: "A private room" },
  { value: "shared_room", label: "A shared room" },
] as const;

const VALUES = ["entire_place", "private_room", "shared_room"] as const;
const Property = z.enum(VALUES);
type Property = z.infer<typeof Property>;
```

However, I don't want to define my data **twice**, **one time with a label** (the label is used for ui purposes), and another without a **label**.

I want to define it only once using the `properties` object, without the `VALUES` array, and use it to create a zod object and infer the type from the zod object.

Any solutions how?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In this case, I think I would infer the type for `Property` from `properties` directly. You can avoid repeating yourself with code like:

```
import { z } from "zod";

const properties = [
  { value: "entire_place", label: "The entire place" },
  { value: "private_room", label: "A private room" },
  { value: "shared_room", label: "A shared room" }
] as const;

type Property = typeof properties[number]["value"];
// z.enum expects a non-empty array so to work around that
// we pull the first value out explicitly
const VALUES: [Property, ...Property[]] = [
  properties[0].value,
  // And then merge in the remaining values from `properties`
  ...properties.slice(1).map((p) => p.value)
];
const Property = z.enum(VALUES);
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. But is it possible that I pass the type to zod and zod automatically creates the enum from the possible values of the type?

Comment: Types don't exist at runtime. All of the type annotations that typescript uses to give you compiler checks will be stripped out and you'll just be left with Javascript. For `zod` to be able to do checks, it needs to have real world values. It's more of a TypeScript issue than a `zod` one. The type system lets you manipulate the types of runtime values with `typeof`, but you can't go in the other direction and manipulate runtime values with types.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, @Souperman! Your response was instrumental in helping me create a helper function to handle this situation. For those who might encounter a similar issue in the future, I've refined and documented the solution based on @souperman's guidance. Here's the helper function that extracts the values from a given enum-like object and returns them in a tuple format:

```
/**
 * `extractValuesAsTuple` extracts the values from a given enum-like object and returns them
 * in a tuple format.
 *
 * This helper is useful when working with libraries or utilities that expect a non-empty tuple
 * of string values, particularly when those utilities cannot accept a simple string array.
 *
 * @template T - The type of the enum-like object. It should be a record of string keys to string values.
 *
 * @param {T} obj - The enum-like object from which values should be extracted.
 *
 * @returns {[T[keyof T], ...T[keyof T][]]} - A tuple containing all the values from the given object.
 * The tuple is guaranteed to have at least one value.
 *
 * @example
 * const Colors = { RED: 'Red', GREEN: 'Green', BLUE: 'Blue' } as const;
 * const colorValues = extractValuesAsTuple(Colors); // ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue']
 *
 * @throws {Error} - Throws an error if the provided object is empty.
 */
function extractValuesAsTuple<T extends Record<string, any>>(
  obj: T
): [T[keyof T], ...T[keyof T][]] {
  const values = Object.values(obj) as T[keyof T][];
  if (values.length === 0)
    throw new Error('Object must have at least one value.');

  // Explicitly extract the first value
  const result: [T[keyof T], ...T[keyof T][]] = [values[0], ...values.slice(1)];

  return result;
}
const properties = [
  { value: "entire_place", label: "The entire place" },
  { value: "private_room", label: "A private room" },
  { value: "shared_room", label: "A shared room" },
] as const;

// Extracting the 'value' properties into a tuple using the helper function
const propertyValues = extractValuesAsTuple(properties.map(p => p.value));

console.log(propertyValues); // ["entire_place", "private_room", "shared_room"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I took the example of the @Ruslan and @Souperman and create a simplified version

My propose is to wrap the z.enum function with `z_enumFromArray`

```js
import { z } from 'zod'
function z_enumFromArray(array: string[]){
  return z.enum([array[0], ...array.slice(1)])
}



// example of user19910212
const properties = [
  { value: "entire_place", label: "The entire place" },
  { value: "private_room", label: "A private room" },
  { value: "shared_room", label: "A shared room" },
] as const;
const propertySchema = z_enumFromArray(properties.map(prop=>prop.value))
propertySchema.parse("entire_place") // pass
propertySchema.parse("invalid_value") // throws error




// Another example using an Object as input
const status = {
  active: "B0A47BD3-5CC2-49EF-BA69-9BC881A2B6C2",
  inactive: "BDABF381-FA76-4578-81EC-FF3E56055A9E",
  pending: "2B517D1B-1710-41A6-B946-7AE2B93C7DDE",
} as const
const statusSchema = z_enumFromArray(Object.keys(status))
statusSchema.parse("active") // pass
statusSchema.parse("invalid_value") // throws error
```